# Highcharts Bubble Chart - How to get the size of the point

Tags: size, highcharts, bubble-chart

I want to format the tooltip of my bubble chart but I need to know what property gets me the size of the bubble.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a formatter function you would do something like this:

```
tooltip :
  formatter: function() {
      return "My bubble size is : " + this.point.z;
  }
}
```

this.point also has the following properties in the bubble chart tooltip formatter: series, x, and y

For more see: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter

Comment: Thatworked!  Thanks.  The API never mentions "z" as a property.  I thought it may be z.  The other thing that threw me is that "this" IS a reference to the point.  I didn't think I needed this.point which seems like we are referencing point.point.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the radius by accecssing `this.point.shapeArgs.r` in `formatter` function. just like the solution by @scott-gearhart